# Apche POI XWPFDocument Memory Leak

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

Im using Apache POI version 5.0.0. Im using it to create Word document and create a very large report from it. Apache POI is taking a lot of memory and after the report is created its not releasing the memory.

I dont want to increase the java heap space but want to flush the memory when the report is generated. I have tried to manually run the garbage collector using Visual VM, but its not clearing the memory either also.

below is the code to reproduce the issue.

```
package com.mi6.word;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;

public class CreateTable {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
    
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("createTable.docx"));
    
    int i = 0;
    
    while(i < 130000) {
        
        System.err.println("Table # "+ i);
        
        XWPFTable table = doc.createTable();
        
        XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(0);
        row.getCell(0).setText("Row 0 Col 0");
        row.addNewTableCell().setText("Row 0 Col 1");
        row.addNewTableCell().setText("Row 0 Col 2");
        
        XWPFTableRow row2 = table.createRow();
        row2.getCell(0).setText("Row 1 Col 0");
        row2.getCell(1).setText("Row 1 Col 1");
        row2.getCell(2).setText("Row 1 Col 2");
        
        XWPFTableRow row3 = table.createRow();
        row3.getCell(0).setText("Row 2 Col 0");
        row3.getCell(1).setText("Row 2 Col 1");
        row3.getCell(2).setText("Row 2 Col 2"); 
        
        i++;
        
    }
    
    doc.write(out);
    
    doc.close();
    
    out.close();
    
    System.out.println("Create Table Write Successfully. ");
    
    //to keep alive the program to check memory is release or not. 
    while(true){
        Thread.sleep(1000);   
    }
    
}
}
```

Comment: is there any difference, if you move the busy loop out of the context of the doc variable?, i.e. try to put the code before in a nested closure.

Comment: I want to replicate the issue, so i create the table in the big loop. The original issue is jvm is not releasing the memory after calling doc.close and out.close, the memory remains fill and not flus, even if i run the garbage collector.

Comment: the doc variable is still referenced in this scope and the garbage collector can't remove it. if you move the second last bracket "}" before the `while (true)`, the garbage collector should be able to remove doc. just by calling close, the baking store / XmlBeans aren't removed.

Comment: Yes you are right i have move the whole method to a separate function but not the thread and when doc is created if i ran the gc it flush out the memory.

Comment: Im wondering if there is someway to release memory when we are creating big report e.g after writing around 2000 pages.

Comment: Sorry to say, but there's no XSWPF (streaming API for Word). You can read sometimes "POI is a memory hog" and this hasn't changed. You can try to increase your heap. If this doesn't work, I probably would write my own generator ... a 2000 pages report sounds like a lot of repetitive tables and the xml behind it is not rocket science.